# BeginBinaryImport in a transaction

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

As far as I can tell, the `COPY` command in Postgres supports transactions, but I don't see a way to specify a transaction with `NpgsqlConnection.BeginBinaryImport`. Is it not supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BeginBinaryImport implicitly participates in a transaction started before it. So just do NpgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction first, and then call BeginBinaryImport.